# sprite collision detection and removing one sprite from group in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

so I need to remove one sprite from the group every time I press the - (minus) key. However, I am confused as to how to do it. Another issue I've run into is when I press the + key it is adding more than one sprite at a time. I'm guessing I need to also check for KEYUP ? I also have a bug where some of the sprites will be created on top of each and will stay stuck bouncing off one another. How can I check for existing sprites where the new will be generated?  Here is my code

dragon.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Dragon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x,y, vx, vy):
        super().__init__();
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/dragon.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(pygame.Color(255,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy

    def draw(self, SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

    def move(self, SCREEN):
        r_collide = self.rect.x + self.image.get_width() + self.vx >= SCREEN.get_width()
        l_collide = self.rect.x + self.vx <= 0
        t_collide = self.rect.y + self.vy <= 0
        b_collide = self.rect.y + self.image.get_height() + self.vy >= SCREEN.get_height()

        # Check collision on right and left sides of screen
        if l_collide or r_collide:
            self.vx *= -1

        # Check collision on top and bottom sides of screen
        if t_collide or b_collide:
            self.vy *= -1

        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.rect.y += self.vy

    def bounce(self, SCREEN):
        self.vy *= -1
        self.vx *= -1
```

dragon_animation.py

```
import pygame
import sys
from random import *
from pygame.locals import *
from flying_dragon.dragon import Dragon


def main():
    pygame.init()

    FPS = 30
    FPS_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    ''' COLOR LIST '''
    WHITE = pygame.Color(255,255,255)

    ''' create initial window '''
    window_size = (500, 500)
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

    ''' set the title '''
    pygame.display.set_caption("Flying Dragons")

    ''' fill background color in white '''
    SCREEN.fill(WHITE)

    ''' group to store dragons '''
    dragons = pygame.sprite.Group()

    d1 = Dragon(0,0,3,2)
    d1.draw(SCREEN)

    dragons.add(d1)

    ''' main game loop '''
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        SCREEN.fill(WHITE)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_PLUS or pygame.K_KP_PLUS:
                d = Dragon(randint(1, SCREEN.get_width() - dragon.rect.x), randint(1, SCREEN.get_height()- dragon.rect.y), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5))
                dragons.add(d)

        for dragon in dragons:
            dragons.remove(dragon)
            collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(dragon, dragons, False)
            dragons.add(dragon)

            for dragon in collisions:
                dragon.bounce(SCREEN)

        for dragon in dragons:
            dragon.move(SCREEN)

        dragons.update(SCREEN)
        dragons.draw(SCREEN)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPS_CLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which dragon do you want to remove? First one? Last one? Random?

Comment: preferably the last one that was added but it doesn't really matter for this particular problem

Answer (score 1):

```
if event.key == pygame.K_MINUS or pygame.K_KP_MINUS:
    dragons.remove(dragons[0])
```

Should work for removing a sprite. Sprites aren't ordered in the group so will just delete a random one.

As another pointer, you should look at redefining your `Dragon.move()` function as dragon.update() then the `Group.update()` call will move all your dragons.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to draw the dragon immediately after it's creation before the while loop. The draw inside the while loop is sufficient.

When you press a key the event list will hold which key you are holding down and as long as this is down a dragon will be created. As the loop runs pretty fast several dragons will be created before you remove your finger from the keyboard.

also good to do

```
pygame.event.pump()
```

before the `for event in pygame.event.get():` so that you clear the event list beofre the next run.

read [about the pygame event pump here.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)

Use `key = pygame.key.get_pressed()` instead of event.get as it will read a key press ONCE.

can't run your code because of this error.

```
ImportError: No module named flying_dragon.dragon
```